# Why does WS-I Basic Profile 2.0 not use WSDL 2.0?

Tags: wsdl, profile, ws-i

With a new major release of the WS-I Basic Profile specification I was expecting to read about the use of WSDL 2.0. Unfortunatly I could not find this...

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I know, not a final answer. The WS-I's mission is (was) not to push new standards into the market, but instead defining a common set of minimum standards to ensure interoperability between different WS-* platforms and vendors.

WSDL 2.0 was designed to solve those interop' issues identified in WSDL 1.0/1.1. So there is simply no need for future Basic Profiles. Some quotes from [here](http://www.w3.org/2007/06/wsdl20-pressrelease):

> http://www.w3.org/ -- 27 June 2007 -- Today, W3C has finalized a Web
>   services description language with full support of the primary
>   protocol for the Web, HTTP, and the most frequently implemented Web
>   services protocol, SOAP. Web Services Description Language (WSDL) 2.0
>   incorporates both the improvements for WSDL 1.1 found in the WS-I
>   Basic Profile, and builds in inheritance, import functions, improved
>   description of faults and errors, and full HTTP and SOAP support.
>   Rigorous testing and interop sessions, including week-long programming
>   marathons by the Web Services Description Working Group itself, have
>   produced a solid interoperable standard that delivers on the goals of
>   the initial WSDL 1.1 version, and also meets the needs of Web
>   applications developers today.

---

> Wide interest in SOAP 1.1 and WSDL 1.1 marked the beginning of Web
>   Services pursuits. The hope of interoperability in the initial,
>   non-standardized versions was not immediately fulfilled in spite of
>   the large number of developers who moved to that model for
>   applications development. WS-I, for example, formed to create profiles
>   based on non-standard versions of the popular Web Services
>   technologies.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't looked at it that way.